# Windows Indexing is not working and I cannot turned it on. What should I do?

Tags: search-indexing

[image]

I try to search stuff in my computer. Indexing not working.

So I try to turn it on. I search for indexing options and this is what I see?

Included location is just empty.

What should I do?

It used to work.

I tried to turn on the service and I got this error message

[image]

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the machine in question?  It does not appear the indexing service is even running.  Can you confirm that is the case?  Instead of submitting a comment, please include all vital information, as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows + R type Services.msc
2. Look for service called "Windows Search"
3. Right click it once you found it and select properties
4. Select the start up type from the drop down menu "automatic"
5. Under service status click "start" then click "ok"
6. Restart computer

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say that the question has been answered in

[How to change directory of windows search without activating windows search?](https://superuser.com/questions/1510315/how-to-change-directory-of-windows-search-without-activating-windows-search/1510336#1510336)

The solution here solves my particular problems.